# kubernetes | docker | no image found error while rolling update

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

Have create updated image  with new tag for rolling but then while performing update with this command: `kubectl set image deployments/hello-node-1 hello-node-1=hello-node:v2`

Getting error: `kubelet, minikube                   Warning     FailedSync  Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "hello-node-1" with ErrImagePull: "rpc error: code = 2 desc = Error: image library/hello-node not found"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you didn't set the image correctly. Did you push it to the correct repository? A way to test it could be to create a new deployment that uses your newly created image.

Comment: Yes actually I was creating image with sudo instead of other user that for solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to the wrong image. The error message shows that the kubelet is attempting to pull `hello-node:v2` as an official image from docker hub (`library/...`).

If you did push your image to **docker hub** then prefix the image name with your docker hub username.

If this is in some **private repository** then prefix it with a repository hostname.

If you **built the image locally on the node** then make sure your `imagePullPolicy` in your Deployment is set to `IfNotPresent` and make sure the image is actually present on all nodes this pod might be scheduled to run on.

For **minikube** check out [this post](https://blog.hasura.io/sharing-a-local-registry-for-minikube-37c7240d0615).